# Allow access to a web admin Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am trying to allow only one ip to connect to my admin in ngnix but it gives me an error 403.
What happens is that the Allow option is not working and I don't know why.
Could you help me?.

My current configuration is as follows:

```
  location ~ ^/(login_admin) {
                allow 1.1.XX.XXX;
                deny all;
     }
```

The page is thepage.com/login_admin

Comment: Did you restart `nginx` after config change?

Comment: Yes! Always but not found.

Comment: which version of nginx are you using?

Comment: Im using "nginx version: nginx/1.16.1"

Comment: i think what is 403 error is ok but when get into my private ip not found my page. I feel what this "allow" its doesn't work